# Using an EventHandler to detect a variable change?

Tags: c#, event-handling

How would you recommend I setup an event handler to fire when a variable is updated with a value > 0.

```
public _price;

public double GetPrice(string item)
{
    _table.GetData += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(ExtractData);

    // Right now I set it to sleep to give it enough time to return the data.
    // But I would like to setup an eventhandler to return the _price when a value is populated
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    return _price;
}

void ExtractData(object sender, DataEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (PriceRecord rec in e)
    {
        if (rec.myprc != null)
            {
                 _price = double.Parse(rec.myprc.Value.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

If I remove Sleep it doesn't have enough time to get the data before returning an incorrect value.  I would like to remove sleep to increase performance and just for my own knowledge.  If there are better alternatives than using an event handler Im open to suggestions.

Any suggestions or advice you have is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: How is the value being populated?  If it's from a component (such as via a text box), place the event handler on that component, not on the value itself.  I'm not understanding why sleep would be needed at all in this case.

Comment: 'What' doesn't have enough time to get the data ?

Comment: I updated the code to show another eventhandler that access a table and pulls the price information I need.  Sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Also, you're leaking resources here.  Every time you call GetPrice a new event handler is added to your table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your design... [there is something wrong with it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

You cannot block the execution of a method with an event, so I don't think that would be a good solution here.

Are you multithreading where it says `//Some code here`?  If so, check into [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx) (if you're using a heavyweight thread) or a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) (if you're using the thread pool) to block he execution of GetPrice until a value has been set.

Without the details of what you're doing I'm not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: I wish you'd shown a little more about the design; there is probably a much better (and simpler) way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/04/15/events.html

Very useful article!